# Scrapy Debug crawled 200 and nothing return

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am working on a crawling project and try to get each endorsement link of a band.

My code is as follows:

[image: my code]

It returned nothing. However, if I put each URL of a band in the `start_url`, it works well. But it will be hard for me to put all the URLs I want manually in the `start_url` field since I am even not sure how many there are...

The log is shown:

[image: log]

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Next time, it would be great if you could put your code directly in the question instead of in an image, that much more helpful, same for the logs

Answer (score 0):

Your restrict xpath expression looks wrong.

You could use the `allow` parameter instead, this is much easier:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'celebrityendorsers.com'
    start_urls = ['https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor('/endorsements/'), callback='parse_url_contents'),
    )

    def parse_url_contents(self, response):
        pass
```

This is the output log:

```
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/playtex-wipes/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/plenish-cleanse/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/play-date-by-sarah-beckham/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/playstation-3/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/playmg/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/playsight/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/play-cloths/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/platinum-league-trading-cards/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/playstation/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
2018-11-22 02:01:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsements/platinum-group/> (referer: https://celebrityendorsers.com/endorsement/)
```

If you really want to use xpath, then try removing `[*]`.

The xpath that you commented looks correct, but the callback is wrong, you cannot use the `parse` callback with a `CrawlSpider`.